# Making no duplicates with ArrayList Java and shortening the array with input

Tags: java

Is there a way I could get my Question List to randomize integers in the list and then make sure there are no duplicates in it? Also I would like the array to be a specific size that I input. Help would be much appreciated.

```
public List<Question> randomize() {
        int amountQuestions = bank.size();
        int i = 0;
        while(i < amountQuestions - 1) { 
            i++;
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * (amountQuestions - 1)); 
            bank.get(random);
            if(bank.contains(random) && !bank.contains(0)) {
                random = (int) (Math.random() * (amountQuestions - 1));
                bank.get(random);
                if(bank.contains(random) && !bank.contains(0)) {
                    random = (int) (Math.random() * (amountQuestions - 1));
                    bank.get(random);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(random);
            random = -1;
        }
        return bank;
    }
```

Comment: The simple way to create a list of N integers without duplicates is: 1) generate a list which contains all the possible integers; 2) shuffle it; 3) take the first N elements.

Comment: What is `bank.get(random);` supposed to do? The only thing that could do is silently do nothing, or fail with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (or an `NPE`, I guess).

Comment: bank.get(random) is used to set the Arraylist I have in my constructor with Questions called bank  to randomize them, I get an error if I try to use an Integer because I am using an Object list I believe called List<Questions> I call this is another test file to print my questions.

Comment: it doesn't set anything - neither the `bank` variable, nor anything in the list referred to by that variable. If you're just trying to randomize the order of a list, `Collections.shuffle(bank)` is all you need.

Comment: Oh wow, Collections.shuffle(bank) is very useful and works to shuffle them! Is there a way I could reduce the order of the list with an input? like if I were to put 3 it would change the list to a 3 items only shuffled?

Comment: no, it shuffles the entire list it is supplied. You can shuffle a sublist (e.g. `Collections.shuffle(bank.subList(0, 3))`, which would shuffle the first 3 elements); it can't shuffle 3 arbitrary elements, though.